# Easy way to find and run any runnable (exe) project in Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

We work in C# in Visual Studio 2013. We have VS solution, and each one of them contains many many projects (>200), some of these projects are startable ones (`exe`, as oppose to `dll`). Each time you want to run one of them you need to

- find it
- set it to startup project
- run

It's annoying a bit, especially the "find it" part. There is no rational to keep all the `exe` in one solution-folder; they orgenized hierarchically by topics all over the solution. Can't change their names either for easy search.

Instead searching them in the **Solution Explorer** Is there any **Runnable Explorer**, where you can see only the runnable ones and right-click on them and run, w/o changing the Startup Project? Maybe there is addon that does it?

Comment: That just a very inefficient way to organize your projects.  Solution files are like cookies, baking two of them doesn't take much more work than baking one.

Comment: @HansPassant: Good point. But it's the tradition here, and I don't know if I could change it. I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual studio 2015 there is combobox in the standard menu to select the active project.